# Prevent one from doing action if one is activated (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good Day, I just want to ask if how can I do these.

I need to prevent one action from doing something if the another action is activated and vice versa . Here's the code i have written so far.

```
if (hit == "spr_player")
    {
        betOnPlayer = true;
        if (betOnBanker)
        {
            Debug.LogError("You already bet on the banker cannot bet on the player"); ;
        }
        else
        {
            if (betOnPlayer)
            {
                bet[0] = chip;
                chips_bet[0].enabled = true;
                Chips(chip, 0);
                Debug.LogError("Betting on the player");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("You can not bet on the Player");
            }
        }
    }

else if (hit == "spr_banker")
    {
        if (betOnPlayer)
        {
            Debug.LogError("You already bet on the banker cannot bet on the player");
            betOnBanker = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (betOnBanker)
            {
                bet[4] = chip;
                chips_bet[4].enabled = true;
                Chips(chip, 4);
                Debug.LogError("Betting on the banker");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("You can not bet on the Banker");
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem here is that I couldn't get to switch it on off . Could someone point out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why your description of what you are trying to do is so insanely vague?

Comment: @Abion47 I'm sorry I just don't know how should I describe it . But as you can see my code is very near to what I am saying . I'm sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I guess your program is that first click is select target, second click is bet.
And when you set the flag to someone, you should also unset another one.

```
if (hit == "spr_player")
{

    if (betOnPlayer)
    {
        // bet on player
    }
    else
    {
        betOnPlayer = true;
        betOnBanker = false;
    }
}
else if (hit == "spr_banker")
{
    if (betOnBanker)
    {
        // bet on banker
    }
    else
    {
        betOnPlayer = false;
        betOnBanker = true;
    }
}
```

**Another answer:**

```
string currentSelect = "";

void Update() {

    if(YOUR_INPUT_EVENT) {
        if (hit == "spr_player")
        {        
            if (currentSelect == "Player")
            {
                // bet on player
            }
            else
            {
                currentSelect = "Player"
            }
        }
        else if (hit == "spr_banker")
        {
            if (currentSelect == "Banker")
            {
               // bet on banker
            }
            else
            {
                currentSelect == "Banker"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wait how will this be triggered if it hits the `spr_player`

Comment: So I'll set first my booleans to true? like this ? `if(....){ betOnPlayer = true; if(betOnPlayer){ } }` like that?

Comment: Even if the initial value of both booleans are false, the logic should be work.

Comment: If that is the case then this will be always on the `else statement`

Comment: Outside or inside else statement? What case you assume?

Comment: I mean i tried your code and on the very top my 2 boolean are declared false `betOnPlayer = false; betOnBanker = false` then put a `Debug.LogError("Cannot bet!")` on your else statement on the both condition and yes they're always there on the `Cannot Bet!`.

Comment: You should only set the boolean when scenes Start(). And when first click to someone, it will enter the else statement. Then click again will enter the if statement.

Comment: still I can bet on both side sir . What should i do

Comment: Use one variable to record select statement. see updated answer.

Comment: Maybe my answer cannot solve your problem directly. But you may get some inspire, and find the point from your original code. Or you should describe your work and problem clear, someone might be able to help you.